# Is it possible to mix Go with other languages to create desktop apps?

Tags: go, desktop-application

I know it's possible to [mix C with Go](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/), but I was wondering if it was possible to mix with other languages too. Specifically, I was wondering if it was possible to write a backend in Go and then use Swift or C# to make a GUI for a desktop app.

Also, is it common to build apps like that? What are the performance costs like? The goal is to write a cross-platform backend, then use native platform tools to create the GUI. So, I would use Swift and Cocoa to make a GUI for OS X and C# and .NET to make a GUI for Windows. That way the applications behave and feel like native apps.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you be able to do that? There's numerous IPC mechanisms you can use.

Comment: Well, I'm not aware of them. That's why I'm asking a question. I don't know everything.

Comment: sorry, but you did ask in the context if Go, and there's nothing Go specific about IPC. You have std io streams, sockets of various types,  FIFOs, shared memory, and so on.

Comment: So, what are some Go-specific packages or code samples I could look at to learn more about IPC done in Go?

Comment: There are many desktop GUI libraries for Go, just search for them, many come up. You can write desktop applications with Go.

Comment: @425nesp [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) isn't a single thing, you can achieve what you want in many different ways. You could expose an http API, or use Go's built-in [rpc](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/) package for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the same sense of using C/C++ with Go, no, however nothing is stopping you from writing the backend in Go and controlling it over http (or stdin/stdout).